# Displaying JSON string on the Browser

Tags: json

I am currently working on developing a python REST API. How can I display JSON string on multi-lines on my Browser?[image]

This is what I want.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this code.

```
 JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(data, null, 4); may not work because I am using flask framework

Comment: oh, you can install Browser Extension JSON Formatter

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome or microsoft edge, you can install extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=id
To pretty print json

Comment: I am going to try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one Chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-%3E-table/pjdecdkdljmchigbkalnblidepkeojda

Install and open JSON in browser